# Why does some file get missed out if i use Parallel.ForEach()?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Following is the code which processes about 10000 files.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(directorypath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(
                    name => !name.EndsWith(".gif") && !name.EndsWith(".jpg") && !name.EndsWith(".png")).ToList();
Parallel.ForEach(files,Countnumberofwordsineachfile);
```

And the `Countnumberofwordsineachfile` function prints the number of words in each file into the text.
Whenever i implement `Parallel.ForEach()`, i miss about 4-5 files everytime while processing.
Can anyone suggest as to why this happens?

```
  public void Countnumberofwordsineachfile(string filepath)
    {
        string[] arrwordsinfile = Regex.Split(File.ReadAllText(filepath).Trim(), @"\s+");
        Charactercount = Convert.ToInt32(arrwordsinfile.Length);
        filecontent.AppendLine(filepath + "=" + Charactercount);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for Countnumberofwordsineachfile

Comment: What do you mean by "prints the number of words?"  Is this a console application that spits out 10000 numbers?  Or do you add the count of words for each file together and then display it at the end?

Comment: Could you post the code of Countnumberofwordsineachfile? Have you checked that the variable files contains the exact number of files you're expecting?

Comment: Can you add the code for the function you are calling, `Countnumberofwordsineachfile`?

Comment: Also, try and get a list of files as they're processed, to find the exact files which are being missed. Will probably show the problem more clearly.

Comment: Have you tried to do the same work in a "regular" loop? and do you have a different result than when using 'Parallel'?

Comment: What is `filecontent` ? a stream? maybe you don't dispose the stream correctly and it doesn't flush the content entirely.

Comment: filecontent is a stringbuilder

Answer (score 4):

`fileContent` is probably not threadsafe. So if two (or more) tasks attempt to append to it at the same time one will win, the other will not. You need to remember to either lock the sections that are shared, or don't used shared data.

This is probably the easiest solution for your code. Locking, synchronises access (other tasks have to queue up to access the locked section) so it will slow down the algorithm, but since this is very short compared to the part that counts the words is likely to be then it isn't really going to be much of an issue.

```
private object myLock = new object();
public void Countnumberofwordsineachfile(string filepath)
{
    string[] arrwordsinfile = Regex.Split(File.ReadAllText(filepath).Trim(), @"\s+");
    Charactercount = Convert.ToInt32(arrwordsinfile.Length);
    lock(myLock)
    {
        filecontent.AppendLine(filepath + "=" + Charactercount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause has already been found, here is an alternative implementation:

```
//Parallel.ForEach(files,Countnumberofwordsineachfile);
var fileContent = files
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(f=> f + "=" + Countnumberofwordsineachfile(f));
```

and that requires a more useful design for the count method:

```
// make this an 'int' function, more reusable as well
public int Countnumberofwordsineachfile(string filepath)
{ ...; return characterCount; }
```

But do note that going parallel won't help you much here, your main function (ReadAllText) is I/O bound so you will most likely see a degradation from using `AsParallel()`.

The better option is to use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and then collect the results without parallelism:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(....);
var fileContent = files
         //.AsParallel()
         .Select(f=> f + "=" + Countnumberofwordsineachfile(f));
```